# Smooth Div Scroll with colorbox not working

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, colorbox, smoothing

Here is a link to the page with the gallery:

http://www.gerardtonti.com/Scrollable%20Gallery%202/index.html

I've tried everything but I'm still having the same issue.  I found your jQuery Smooth Div Scroll tool online. I'm planning to donate but I'm having trouble making it work with the colorbox option like you have on your site: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/colorbox.html

I'm a graphic artist and web designer looking for a gallery option to show my work. It seems that when I add the a href-tag that links to the large image it breaks the scrollable gallery. I have a colorbox.css file linked in the head section of my html as:

```
<code>link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" /></code>
```

I also have this in the body of the document:

```
<code><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Init Smooth Div Scroll   
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
manualContinuousScrolling: true
});

// Init colorbox
$("#makeMeScrollable a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
</code>
```

I have the same images in the gallery repeating and will replace them once I figure out what it wrong. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Here is the complete HTML source:

```
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo - jQuery Smooth Div Scroll - Thomas Kahn</title>

<!-- the CSS for Smooth Div Scroll -->
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothDivScroll.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" />

<!-- Styles for my specific scrolling content -->
<style type="text/css">

    #makeMeScrollable
    {
        width:100%;
        height: 330px;
        position: relative;
    }

    /* Replace the last selector for the type of element you have in
       your scroller. If you have div's use #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div,
       if you have links use #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea a and so on. */
    #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
           block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
           accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
    <a href="images/charcoal_Big.jpg"><img src="images/charcoal.jpg" alt="charcoal" id="field" /></a>
</div>

<!-- LOAD JAVASCRIPT LATE - JUST BEFORE THE BODY TAG 
     That way the browser will have loaded the images
     and will know the width of the images. No need to
     specify the width in the CSS or inline. -->

<!-- jQuery library - Please load it from Google API's -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI Widget and Effects Core (custom download)
 You can make your own at: http://jqueryui.com/download -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Latest version of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
 You will find it here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos -->
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery Kinetic - for touch -->
<script src="js/jquery.kinetic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
 js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js -->
<!-- Colorbox -->
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
     js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js -->

<!-- Plugin initialization -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// Init Smooth Div Scroll   
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
    manualContinuousScrolling: true
});

// Init colorbox
$("#makeMeScrollable a").colorbox({ speed: "500" });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Ger

Comment: perhaps you don't have enough images to scroll yet?

Comment: I thought that might be the case as well, but there are plenty of images in there.

Comment: try giving the images different ids.

Comment: tried different ids and that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your example is working now, everything is ok with html-markup, just set width for div:

```
<div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 4000px;">
```

**Added:**

`scrollableArea` calculated with jquery, it's hard to debug `min` version, but as I understand `makeMeScrollable` div must be wrapped with another div with fixed width.

**Added 2:**

Now it's works fine. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fDGJH/

Set this styles:

```
#makeMeScrollable
{
    width:100%;
    height: 330px;
    position: relative;
}

#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried <div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 4000px;"> <div id="makeMeScrollable"></div></div> and this didn't work.

Comment: try style="width: 4000px !important;"

Comment: @user1741568 This code is rendered with jquery and on your page width = 0, try add `<div id="wrapper">` with fixed width.

Comment: I have tried <div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 4000px !important;" > and it does not work.  It controls the width of the gallery but the pictures are still missing.

Comment: I might just purchase a gallery online. Asad and webdeveloper, thanks for taking a look though.

Comment: maybe it doesn't like the same image being used over and over? don't know why that would cause an issue though.

Comment: I'm really stumped. Looked over all the code and I don't see anything different.

Comment: Could I possibly zip up the files and send them to you?

Comment: The demo above works great! Thank you, but I am unable to replicate on my home machine when I type in the same styles?

Comment: Would someone mind looking at one more thing? I have four galleries on the main page now all using the Smooth Div Scroll.  Some images are placeholders but I just want to make sure the gallery is functioning.  I cannot understand why the fourth scrollable gallery is coming in different and larger than the first three? Here is the link again:  http://www.gerardtonti.com/Scrollable%20Gallery%202/index.html        I can post source if needed.  I'm just not sure how to do hat in a comment section without running into character limits.  Maybe post another topic?

Comment: @user1741568 Please, set answer as correct and look at another answer in your new question.